# Mirror modifier wont merge

Tags: objects, vertices, mirror, mirror-modifier

When I apply the mirror modifier, the vertices that are very close together (About 0.000001 m apart) won't merge and I've tried to fix this by changing the settings of the mirror modifier but nothing seems to work.

Here is an image to explain the situation better:
[image]

Here's the [file](https://pasteall.org/blend/30dd41d4e77544318416c0281544072f)

Comment: hello could you please share the file? https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: I added it now.

Comment: if my solution don't work, please provide your blend file with not applied mirror modifier so we can check it out (looks like you meant the blade object, is that right?)

Comment: in the file you share, the object has no Mirror modifier, please provide a file with the Mirror modifier. Also make sure that your vertices don't go beyond the mirror axis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to check the "merge" checkbox in the mirror modifier. And sometimes you have to increase the value right beside the merge that it works.

[image]

Comment: I already tried that and it didn't work no matter what I set the merge limit to

Comment: which object do you mean in your file? i think you already applied mirror modifier, right?

Comment: the merge will work...you made something wrong

Comment: Right now i have the merge checked with 0.001 m and now I'm going to press apply

Comment: just upload the non applied modifier...please...else we cannot check it

Comment: Same result, maybe I need to restart blender?

Comment: you can try, but i think this is not the cause...please upload the not applied modifier. thanks.

Comment: Oh it worked. ill send the non mirrored file anyways

Comment: glad i could help. Happy blending.